# I cant get the bump to show up on this soil texture

Tags: texturing

I need to have this look like real soil because its going to be viewed from a straight on view and I cant seem to get the bump right with my nodes.

[image: soil]
nodes
[image: nodes]
Blender file
[image]

Comment: Two things I see : In your texture coordinate node your UV map should be in the object selection box. Your Math Node is set to "ADD" it should be set to "MULTIPLY. Also you should have an additional "Texture Coordinate Node and "Image Texture Node for the "Displacement" socket

Comment: Also If you need real displacement either feed your texture to a displace modifier or use the 'true displacement' feature available with experimental feature set. Its does the same thing but displace modifier cannot use cycles textures so this is a way around.

Comment: when I change to object it just adds tiled squares generated in image coordinates actually makes it look better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, try changing where it says *Add* to *Multiply*. I also notice that you are viewing the soil at a pretty shallow angle, rather than perpendicular or slightly less (optimal for node based bump). If you are going to continue to do this, I would suggest also using the *Displace* Object modifier along with the node based bump as demonstrated at about 57:52 [here](https://youtu.be/mxAsfqqeAUM).

Comment: the displace object modifier worked great thanks

Comment: I didn't do the node based bump but worked tas good as for what I need

Comment: Glad to help! @BenSmith